Lemma for Clarkson Inequality
In my functional analysis course the instructor mentioned the following lemma:
(i)If $1<p<2$, then for any complex number $z,w$, we have $|{z+w\over 2}|^q+|{z-w\over 2}|^q\le ({1\over 2}(|z|^p+|w|^p))^{1\over p-1}$, where $q={p\over p-1}$ is the Hölder conjugate of $p$.
(ii) If $2<p<\infty$, then $|{z+w\over 2}|^p+|{z-w\over 2}|^p\le {1\over 2}(|z|^p+|w|^p)$.
I can see that (ii) follows easily from (i), but I cannot prove (i).
Here is my attempt:
Since $1<p<2$ we have $0<p-1<1$.
Then $(|{z+w\over 2}|^q+|{z-w\over 2}|^q)^{p-1}\le |{z+w\over 2}|^{q(p-1)}+|{z-w\over 2}|^{q(p-1)} =|{z+w\over 2}|^p+|{z-w\over 2}|^p$
$\le  {1\over 2}^p(|z|^p+|w|^p+|z|^p+|w|^p)={1\over 2}^{p-1}(|z|^p+|w|^p)$
However, I noticed that ${1\over 2}^{p-1}>{1\over 2}$. Can somebody give me hints on how to prove part (i)?
